# Is there a measure for similarity of a shape to a circle? (2D analog of Willmore energy)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, curvature

[Willmore energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_energy) measure how much a given surface deviates from a sphere. I wonder if there is a **measure for how much a given periphery deviates from a circle**. Something like a 2D analog of Willmore energy.

I found the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) to be one reliable measure for this. But I am not entirely sure, if it is the best or the only quantitative measure.

Comment: Naive construction: Consider a smooth closed curve $\gamma\colon \Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb R^2$.
Let $\kappa\colon \Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb R$ be the curvature of $\gamma$.
Define $\kappa_0 = \frac{1}{\mathrm{length}(\gamma)}\int_{\gamma} \kappa$ be the average curvature of $\gamma$.
Consider
$$
W(\gamma) = \int_{\gamma}\left(\kappa-\kappa_0\right)^2.
$$
Then $W \geqslant 0$, and $W=0$ if and only if $\kappa \equiv \kappa_0$, that is if $\gamma$ has constant curvature.
Since $\gamma$ is closed, this is equivalent to $\gamma$ being a circle of radius $R= \frac{1}{\kappa_0}$.

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions. Why the integrand is squared? And how a similar construction would look like if the curve is not smooth but have cusps?

Comment: I squared it to have a non-negative value, as usual for energy functions. If the curve is not smooth, there should be some corrections term I guess, depending on the cusps/ angles, but I can't say much. Note that I just made up this construction (this does not mean that it comes out of nowhere)

Comment: Another though for the squared integrand: it is similar to the fact that for an integrable function, $\int f$ can be zero without $f$ being close to zero at all, but $\int f^2 = 0$ implies that $f$ is equal to zero almost everywhere. Of course on can consider absolute value instead, but the resulting expression looses some differentiability property with respect to its entry.

Comment: Another measure is based on the ratio $R/r$ of the resp. radii of the smallest enclosing circle and the biggest enclosed circle (these circles they need not be concentrical)